# No redirection by Firefox after 302 response from CORS POST request

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, cors, http-status-code-302

From Firefox v21.0 browser, I am making a CORS POST request with *json* data to my API server (hosted at `http://localhost:8083`) using jQuery.ajax() call:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8083/nscl/applications",
        data: JSON.stringify({resID:"na001"}),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { alert(data); },
        failure: function(errMsg) { alert(errMsg); }
      });
```

The API server returns a **302 OK** response with a Location header. However, the browser stops at the POST response and does not proceed with the redirection.

The XML tab of firebug shows:

> XML Parsing Error: no element found Location:
>   moz-nullprincipal:{649cd3d9-5b8a-4ebc-a883-b0466f19e380} Line Number
>   1, Column 1:

If I change the CORS POST request to use *x-www-form-urlencoded* data, the browser is able to follow the redirection with a GET request:

```
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:8083/nscl/applications",
        data: "resID=na001",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) { alert(data); },
        failure: function(errMsg) { alert(errMsg); }
      });
```

How to make Firefox to follow the redirection URL when the request data type is json?

Thanks.

Comment: You really should avoid redirecting POSTs. A comment from the chromium sources: `The draft also allows POST requests to be converted to GETs when following 301/302 redirects, for historical reasons. Most major browsers do this and so shall we.` In HTTP/1.1 protocol the `307` status code was introduced `[...] In contrast to how 302 was historically implemented, the request method is not allowed to be changed when reissuing the original request. For instance, a POST request should be repeated using another POST request.` (But honestly i don't know which browser support 307 redirects).

Comment: No choice if you are using third-party servers which follow POST-Redirect-GET paradigm. Found out that if I make the same POST request from the same domain (http://localhost:8083), everything works fine.